# "Bring the house down"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, idioms

What is a group or person called who "brings the house down" or "can bring the house down"?

Comment: [Bring the house down](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bring?q=bring+down+the+house#bring__14)

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary’s definition is ‘to evoke such demonstrative applause as threatens or suggests the downfall of the building.’

I have always supposed it to be derived from the music hall, where a particularly good act might, with a little exaggeration, bring about such an event. It may now be found in wider contexts.

Comment: As for the person, in that meaning, that would be the *Star*.

Comment: In regard to your "wider contexts" remark, I believe this phrase can also refer to a comedian who gives an especially funny performance; i.e.: _He brought the house down with [laughter.](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22brought+the+house+down+with+laughter%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)_

Comment: @J.R. Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the company, contractor or person that demolishes your old house or building, then use *demolisher* or *demolition guy(s)*, *demolition contractor*, etc.

Comment: Very unlikely that a question tagged "idiom" was looking for a literal meaning of the phrase